# How to send custom logs to Google Play Developer Console?

Tags: android, google-play

I had uploaded my android application to **Google Play**. My application is running fine. But on some devices, it have some issues. Whenever my application gets crashed Google Play Developer Console received that error. It's like:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.asdasd.dfgdfgdfgd/com.asdasd.dfgdfgdfgd.SplashScreenActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1659)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1675)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:121)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:943)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:227)
```

With this kind of Log i can't find which android device producing that error & with what android OS.

**Is there any way to send custom Logs to developer console on Application Crash?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - how to send crash reports?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10815049/android-how-to-send-crash-reports)

Answer (score 2):

No and the Android automatic error reporting is not worth using. The user comments are separated from the error and you get no indication of which device it came from.

Try out http://www.bugsense.com/ as it is much more comprehensive and free for low usage.  You can add custom additions to your logs with this but only on the paid accounts.

Update:
Bugsense is now Splunk. Another option is https://fabric.io

Comment: Thankx buddy. i'll give a shot to BugSense.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question. The question was "Is there any way to send custom Logs to developer console on Application Crash?"

Comment: I believe any reasonable person would see that the answer (from 2.5 years ago) was an implied "No". I would question the motive of such comments as after such a length of time they really add nothing useful. Did you need to reactivate an old question to get a badge? You could have simply edited the answer (added 2 words) to fit with what you think I should have said.

Comment: Update: Fabric SDK appears to be obsolete. from [official docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports?platform=android):

"The Fabric SDK is now deprecated and will continue reporting your app's crashes until November 15, 2020. On this date, the Fabric SDK and old versions of the Firebase Crashlytics SDK will stop sending crashes for your app. To continue getting crash reports in the Firebase console, make sure you upgrade to the Firebase Crashlytics SDK versions 17.0.0+ for Android and 4.0.0+ for iOS."