# Send handled exception logs to Google Play Console

Tags: android, google-analytics, splunk

In my Android app, I'm handling some exceptions so as not to crash the app on runtime, and to allow the user to have some (limited) functionality of the app.

However, I want to be able to view the logs of any handled exceptions on the apps of my users.

I've already looked at a few answers on different ways of doing this (such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183923/how-to-send-custom-logs-to-google-play-developer-console)).

I've found out about:

- [Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/exceptions)
- [Splunk Mint](https://mint.splunk.com/)
- [Fabric](https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/caught-exceptions.html?caught%20exceptions#caught-exceptions)

They all seem very similar, so before I jump in and start implementing one of these solutions, my question is: **what are the advantages and disadvantages of these tools?**

For example, how does Fabric compare to Google Analytics?