# How to debug a nexus 10? Needs usb charger but need usb connected to debug

Tags: android, usb, galaxy-nexus, usb-debugging

Has anyone found a good solution to debug a galaxy nexus as it gets power?

I can only debug and use the nexus 10 while its plugged into my computer.  I can only charge the nexus 10 when its plugged into a wall.

It charges from USB so what am I suppose to do short of rooting the device and using ADB connect to its IP address?

Do they make cables? Are there ways to send more amps through a USB slot? would a USB hub work?

Something, anything? This is truly a nightmare

Answer (score 1):

I see you're leaning towards a hardware solution, but my answer is more of a workaround I am using:
I assume that most of your debugging you do on emulators, but if you just need to know what's crashing your app on nexus 10, **maybe you can try ACRA** to get the stack trace. I found it very useful as I cannot test all devices and all versions, plus my IDE is on a VM without USB support... I call it "poor man's debugging".
More on this post: [android - how to send crash reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10815049/android-how-to-send-crash-reports)

Comment: That's not a bad idea. Combine that idea with aLogCat https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat (which is a logcat application running on the device itself and which can be controlled through open intents apparently, so perhaps it could even send you back the logs through wifi)

Comment: Actually, aLogCat no longer seems to be useful on Jelly Bean. It's only giving me information on the heap. And even the developer mode setting seems to be finding the last application I was debugging on the device, but it still won't give me its logcat information even if I set it specifically as the application I'm currently debugging/running. I'm afraid Google messed everything up when it made logcat more secure.

Answer (score 0):

If it was me, I would get two USB cables (1 Nexus 10 cable and another USB-USB cable) and splice the power leads from one into the Nexus 10 cable. That way you could then plug the Nexus 10 cable from computer to Nexus 10, and the other cable from your wall charger.

Of course, you have to be comfortable doing this, and sure of your soldering.

EDIT 1: I should also note, that you might wish to look into the POGO pins on the side of your Nexus 10. I believe that these can be used to charge the device (I'm sure a little bit of googling will confirm this). You could see if there are any docks out yet (There weren't when I last checked a couple months back) that could be used to charge it, leaving the USB connection free.

Comment: the pogo is a good idea - not so sure about the usb splicing (work with electrical engineers so comfortable doing it) but would question if would actually work - USB on the computer isn't a serial connection its an active connection so if the USB is not drawing power from the port I would assume the computer wouldn't know anything is connected?

Comment: Well, splicing would mean drawing power from both the computer and the wall charger, wouldn't it? Then the computer would know something is connected...Also, it would be similar to an external HDD caddie, one powered by a DC adapter.

Comment: A spliced USB cable will *not* charge the Nexus 10.

Comment: @turboj care to expand on why?

Comment: The sliced cable works as a data cable, so the tablet thinks it is connected to a USB data port - which allows only 500 mA maximum current. Look into the USB Battery Charger spec for details.

Comment: It may be worth checking if the tablet is getting at least that maximum listed 500 mA as Turbo J referenced. If it's getting less than 1000 mA, it's undercharging, that much is clear, but the cable could even be doing worse than 500 mA. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vexedbadger.chargertimer

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind to root your device, or already have done this. ADB over WIFI could be an option. You can find the directions for ADB over TCP in this post:
[How can I connect to Android with ADB over TCP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp)

Comment: The OP is a aware of this solution as the question states "short of rooting the device and using ADB connect to its IP address".

Comment: @Leco sorry did not notice that.